# Magento Connect Manager / 404 Error / Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404, admin

Path 
Admin > System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager

What I have tried.

- Searched / read every post I can find on it
- Reset folder and file permissions
- Cleared cache
- Re-indexed everything
- logout / login

I migrated from Debian to Centos 5, not sure what the issue would be.

File Permissions

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo chmod o+w var app/etc
sudo chmod 550 mage 
sudo chmod -R o+w media
```

Url that shows 404 page

```
http://my-website.com/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2F...
```

**Edit:**
Magento 404  page - "Whoops, our bad..." page is displayed.

**Solved:**

I deleted downloader folder and uploaded the one from the previous/debian site and it started working.

Comment: Which Magento 404 page are you seeing?  There's many, and each one indicates a different sort of problem. http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

Comment: I added more info, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This method works for me  to fix Magento Connect Manager 404 page not found error:**

Change permission of Directory /downloader/ set to 755 and file /downloader/index.php set to 644.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change some magento files permissions.
to do that please use this solution of [magento-cleanup.php](http://www.techjam.gr/techjamwp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/magento-cleanup.zip)

1. Download it
2. Unzip magento-cleanup.php to the root directory of your magento
   installation
3. Browse to http://yourdomain.com/magento/magento-cleanup.php
4. it's done!

Comment: The link for the "magentp-cleanup.php" file has been updated to this one:
https://tzamtzis.gr/tzamtziswp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/magento-cleanup.zip

Answer (score 0):

Did all the above, but realised I was using Nginx and so it turned out to be not loading the default /downloader/index.php automatically.

Accessing the connect manager directly worked for me: www.example.com/downloader/index.php

Then added some restrictions in nginx conf to restrict to my IP address ore present basic auth login:-

```
location ~ /downloader/ {
    satisfy all;
    allow 1.2.3.4; #SET TO YOUR IP
    deny all;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd; #path to your password file, if there is one!
    autoindex off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Page Not found for Magento connect manager

Go and enable your Downloader folder

magento/downloader keep permision 755 in your server (LAMP ot NGINX)